# Azure Search blob metadata split multiple values and map to indexer as seperate values

Tags: azure, metadata, facet, azure-cognitive-search

I am building an Azure search experience to index and search files in blob storage. The blobs have metadata applied (which I am applying through an azure function).

I am mapping the metadata values to FACETS to refine search results.

My question is about multiple values for the same metadata field. Eg a document has a "Geography"  of "London", "UK" and "Europe".

At which point should we split the metadata into different values? I am not sure it is possible to apply multiple values to a metadata tag, other than using a delimeter like a comma or other character?

Or in the indexer - can we use a "Split" function somewhere to seperate our "London;UK;Europe" as 3 different values?

Or in the end user experience, should we split the FACETS returned by the character (this gives wrong "totals")

Seems like I am missing something easy for a very typical use case - metadata with multiple values.

Comment: are you using the default indexer or have you coded your own?

Comment: Created my own in the portal, with some added JSON to use the FieldMapper function.

Comment: I would recommend you code your own indexer. You will have more freedom on how to model and extract the content before sending it to your index.

Comment: Provide the index defination and sample output of your data.